# Proof about affine varieties

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

Ok so I have that $k$ is algebraically closed and $F$ is an element of $k^n$, and it is a reduced polynomial. We have that $V = V(F)$. In the book it says prove that $F$ generates $I(V)$ but in my assignment it says prove $F$ generates $V(F)$. So I am a little extra confused. I am not looking for a straight up answer, I just want a bit of help, I feel stuck as to how to start. Thank you

Comment: The book is correct while the assignment is not. $F$ should be an element of $k[X_1,\cdots, X_n]$ i.e a polynomial, not a point. You have $V=V(F)$, the points in $k^n$ which cause $F$ to vanish. $F$ is a polynomial, and generates an ideal of $k[X_1,\cdots, X_n]$ like your book tells you. It does not make sense for it to generate $V(F)$, a set of points in $k^n.$

Comment: Ok thank you for clarifying that.I am still confused as to how to begin. So I am being asked to prove the fact that F generates an ideal?

Comment: Not just any ideal. You have to prove that $F$ generates $I(V(F)).$ Hints: Hilbert's Nullstellensatz tells you something relevant here. The fact that $F$ is irreducible is crucial. EDIT: On second thought, this is a special case of the Nullstellensatz that is reasonably easy to prove, so maybe this was given to be solved without the Nullstellensatz.

Comment: Thank you. I am very sorry, I am genuinely not just trying to get the answer from you, but as you can probably tell commutative algebra is not my strong point. Have you any hints as to how to start it off/what exactly to look at.

Comment: Sections 1.2 to 1.7 of Fulton's [Algebraic Curves](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf) is relevant here. That is pages 4-10 of the main text. If you know that much then this problem is easy. Can you tell us what you know about affine varieties so far?

Comment: To be honest not an awful lot. It was only through Google i knew it was called an affine variety. I missed a class last week so perhaps it was discussed then i can't get the missed notes until tomorrow. All i know is the definition and just today the nullstellensatz

Comment: Well if your class has learned the Nullstellensatz that it has probably covered all the material in the part of Fulton's book that I referenced. Don't wait to get the missed notes, just read the first 10 pages of Fulton (just reading the text, not doing the exercises as this will vastly increase how long it takes to get what you need). For your problem, you just need the Nullstellensatz and that $\text{Rad}(I)=I$ if $I$ is a prime ideal.

Comment: Thanks so much i briefly looked at it there and will study it in more detail. It seems very helpful so far. Thank you so much again. Is it possible on this site to give you points or something for your answer? U have been very helpful

Comment: It would have been possible if I put what I've said into an answer down below (so far these have all just been comments, not answers). But it seems you are on the right track already, and I don't need any more of these points than the 16,000+ that I already have.

Comment: Ok thanks very much for your help